# String concat, test, add extra code or add anyway and remove at the end?

Tags: javascript, performance

Sorry for the odd title, I'm sure someone has asked something similar before.  My question is, I'm building a string with html tags enclosed, my question is is it better to test and add extra tags, in this case a `<br />`, or to add the tag anyway and have a 'remove' line at the end, which is faster?:

So at the moment we have

```
bFirst = true;
label = '';

if(...)
{
  if (!bFirst)
  label += '<br/>';

  label+= 'some more text'
}

if(...)
{
  if (!bFirst)
  label += '<br/>';

  label+= 'some more text'
}
```

and so on...

or

```
if()
{
  label+= 'some more text <br />'
}
```

and then just remove the last `<br />` using the string.substring() method.

Which is faster, better, more correct?  I don't need code it is really a performance question, I could test it but I'm sure someone has done this before.

Thanks.

Comment: The difference in processing speed is negligibly small. Unless you are calling that method a million times per second.

Comment: My guess is that what you are really looking for is `Array`s `.join` method

Comment: Inserting into an array and then joining later wouldn't be different from the first strategy the OP already has in consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define which way is the fastest with this procedure :

**Requirements :**
You will need an addon like [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) or [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)

You'll have to execute those two pages :

**Add all extra text and then trim some :**

```
<div id ="concat"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var someText = ""
// adds "foo" 10k times
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    someText += "foo"
}

// crops the 3 last characters off the string 5k times
for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    someText.substr(someText.length - 3, someText.length);
}

// append the final string
$('#concat').append(someText);
</script>
```

On my browser, it takes between 0.19 sec and 0.30 sec.

**Add extra text when it is needed**

```
<div id ="if"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var someText = ""
var append = true;
for (i = 0; i < 15000; i++) {
    //adds "foo" the first 10k times
    if(append == true){
        someText += "foo";
    }
    if(i == 10000){
        append = false;
    }
}
$('#if').append(someText);
</script>
```

This code iterates 15k times and only adds "foo" the first 10k times.

The execution of such code can take between 0.10 and 0.12 sec

**Conclusion**

Adding content to your string only when it is needed seems a better option in terms of performance.
Also, in terms of code readabilty, the second option should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple analysis:

- First option makes a comparison and a memory reallocation.
- Second option (supposing you'd be doing `label = label.substring(...)`) counts characters, if you want the first ***N*** characters, `String.prototype.substring()` will *probably* count ***N*** times while reading ***N*** bytes of characters. Finally, you allocate/reallocate memory.

Now which strategy appears more efficient?

If you're still in doubt try both methods under a timer.

Comment: I know the code, and math I was simply curios to know if anybody had already done it or if someone had created a standard method; I thought I said as much!

Comment: You may consider my answer as an additional support to your current understanding. Meanwhile, did you confirm the accepted answer?